how would you count the occurrences of a datetime (with start and end) every time it appears on an Hour
I am struggling to create a metrics or anything that can achieve this problem.
here is the scenario, for example
Shift_id: 123
shift_start 16/08/2024 07:00
shift_end 16/08/2024 11:00
Shift_id: 456
shift_start 16/08/2024 06:00
shift_end 16/08/2024 13:00
output
so, I want an hourly count for every time a staff is present base on his start/end shift.
hour should be 0-23
can't do sql queries as we have the data directly in MSTR
a solution for the problem, maybe a step by step process
